# How to refresh a screen when you are not using listviews or flatlists?

Tags: react-native

I'm building a mobile app using react-native.
The main screen is a combination of different classes (different js files) that fetches different json urls.
I need to refresh index.js every time the user pulls down the screen.
How can I do this without listviews or flatviews?
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm for the same.

1) install `npm i react-native-pull-to-refresh --save`

2) Then use below code for the refresh.

```
`import PTRView from 'react-native-pull-to-refresh';
    var PullToRefreshProject = React.createClass({
      _refresh: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(()=>{resolve()}, 2000)
        });
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
          <PTRView onRefresh={this._refresh} >
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                Let's Pull!
              </Text>
            </View>
          </PTRView>
        );
      },
    });`
```

Ref link:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pull-to-refresh